# Sed output before substitute

Tags: sed, curl, filter

I am trying to do some `sed` operation while substituting output.
The specific case is the following:
with output `Date:080910 111411` I want to only keep `Date:XXXXXX` and filter out the space with the remaining digits. Normally, a `s/Date:[0-9]{6}//g` would do the trick right?
But the `Date:080910 111411` output comes from a `curl` command where we retrieve it from an API.
This is the `sed` that actually writes it:

```
sed 's/;Submitted-on   *:/ Date:/g'
```

In have been trying to filter that output but I cannot understand where I can out the sed to kill the time out of the date and just give me raw yymmdd.

Anybody has any idea?

Answer (score 1):

- Did you remember to set option `-E` for extended regular expression? Otherwise, you'd need to write `\{6\}` (basic regular expression syntax)
- Your `s/Date:[0-9]{6}//g` will delete that part you actually seem to want to keep
- If you want to remove the space and following digits, do exactly that: `sed 's/ [0-9]*$//'`

Comment: Thank you for the Answer, Philippe!
In order to account for the final space and anything after a modification of your answer did the trick.
I used this: sed 's/ [0-9]* / /'

Answer (score 0):

This will only keep `Date:XXXXXX`:

```
echo "Date:080910 111411" | sed 's/ .*//'
```

And this is more strict, and also preserving the start with "Date:":

```
echo "Date:080910 111411" | sed -r 's/^Date:([0-9]{6}) .*$/\1/'
```